# utf8 error code, aka things strangely changed to Asian symbols

Tags: python, linux, utf-8

Not sure what is going on.  I have several python programs that, some that change csv file data over to kml files, others that remove multiple data entries in csv files, etc that mysteriously started misbehaving yesterday.

I'm using Linux Mint 17.3, which was reinstalled in the 1-1.5 weeks after a similiar situation arose.  Before I did have several other reasons for reformatting and reinstalling Linux.  This time none of the other reasons are there but this problem has crept up again and is making so I can't do much of anything right now.

The first occurence came yesterday afternoon by only changing the filename within one of the programs, nothing else in the code was changed.  It went from working fine, this time yesterday afternoon to in the evening I was getting an error code, don't remember what the actual error code was right now but I knew it was quite strange.

This morning as I went back to working on a differnt part of this massive project all off a sudden I was taking csv file file and converting it over to put placemarks on a kml file.  This time around I was getting the error code:

utf-8 codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0:invalid start byte

I was totally stumped, only to get much worse very soon.

I decided after 10-15 minutes of fighting with it to put it aside and wait until I got the chance to get online.  Instead I moved on trying to combine several csv files and remove multiple entries.  As I went to open the first csv file it came up with Libre Office start screen and showed the Chinese/Japanese/Korean/whatever they are on the screen instead of the plain English that I should be seeing.  If I change the csv file over to a txt file it comes up just fine and displays normally.  Turns out any file much over 10Kb I have this trouble with.  Small csv files will open fine but anything with any kind of size to it won't open up correctly/not open up at all.

I'm not really sure what the heck is going on but this is the second time this has happened in the past two weeks.  What is and how do I eliminate this problem?  I'm not even really sure where to post this question because it is effecting so many different things.

Yes, the files I'm trying to open was opening up yesterday at this time just fine and the programs I was trying to use were working just fine.

Comment: Can you upload one of those messy files in order to investigate a little more?

Comment: I'm not sure how to upload a file.  I seriously think the file isn't the problem as files that I haven't touched in a couple of weeks now don't come up right in Libre Office Calc, and they used to come up fine.  Now they look like Asian writing.  It almost acts like the utf8 file must be getting corrupted, it's the only thing I can think of since it effects both Libre Office and Python.

Comment: You've probably screwed up the locale on your machine.

Comment: How do you check and see if that is the case.  I tried going into Preferences/Languages and both Language and Region both showed English,United States utf-8.  I'm not sure what else to check.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Include example data and code. At the moment, there's far too much conjecture and possibilities - it's too hard to work out what might have happened.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your files have been saved with an encoding of `utf-16`, but you are trying to read them as if they are encoded as `utf-8`.

The bytes `0xff0xfe` are the little-endian `utf-16` [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16), or `BOM`, bytes at the start of some text files which tell programs how the file is encoded.

```
>>> s = u'abc'
>>> s16 = s.encode('utf-16')
>>> s16
b'\xff\xfea\x00b\x00c\x00'
>>> s16.decode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

So you could try to recover your data by reading the files, decoding and then re-saving:

```
>>> with open('s16.txt', 'rb') as f:
...     encoded = f.read()
...     with open('new-file.txt', 'w') as outfile:
...         outfile.write(encoded.decode('utf-16'))
... 
3
>>> with open('new-file.txt') as f:
...     f.read()
... 
'abc'
```

I'd recommend saving to different with filenames, or backing up your corrupted files before doing this, so that if it doesn't work you can get back to your current state.

If this approach fixes your data you are left with the question of what caused the corruption.  Possibly some application or process is (re-)writing these files as `utf-16`: perhaps check the last modified times to see if you can match the changes to any specific action that you took, or cron task.  Or as @MattDMo suggested, perhaps your locale settings have been messed up at some point.